# Dice Rolling Simulator, 2 Dice

Tags: c

I am trying to simulate a game where the program asks the user how many times they would like to roll a pair of dice. The program will then display how many times each total was rolled. We are not allowed to use arrays My program is not rolling or counting random numbers. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int d2 = 0;
    int d3 = 0;
    int d4 = 0;
    int d5 = 0;
    int d6 = 0;
    int d7 = 0;
    int d8 = 0;
    int d9 = 0;
    int d10 = 0;
    int d11 = 0;
    int d12 = 0;

    int k, roll_1, roll_2, num_roll, total,  count = 0 ;

    srand((long)time(NULL));

    printf("Enter number \n");

    scanf("%d", &num_roll);


    for (k = 0; k < num_roll; k++)
    {
        roll_1 = rand() %6 +1;
        roll_2 = rand() %6 +1;
        total = roll_1 + roll_2;
        count++;
    }

    for (k = 0; k < num_roll; k++)
            {
              if (total == 2) d2++;
            else if (total == 3) d3++;
            else if (total == 4) d4++;
            else if (total == 5) d5++;
            else if (total == 6) d6++;
            else if (total == 7) d7++;
            else if (total == 8) d8++;
            else if (total == 9) d9++;
            else if (total == 10) d10++;
            else if (total == 11) d11++;
            else if (total == 12) d12++;
  for(k = 0; k < num_roll; k++)
            {
            perc = total / num_roll;
            }

     printf("Rolls: %i\n", num_roll);

     printf("  2: %d\n", d2);
     printf("  3: %d\n", d3);
     printf("  4: %d\n", d4);
     printf("  5: %d\n", d5);
     printf("  6: %d\n", d6);
     printf("  7: %d\n", d7);
     printf("  8: %d\n", d8);
     printf("  9: %d\n", d9);
     printf("  10: %d\n", d10);
     printf("  11: %d\n", d11);
     printf("  12: %d\n", d12);

   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Where is `perc` declared?

Comment: "Not allowed to use arrays"? That's nuts, especially if the suggested solution is to have variables called d1,d2 etc.

Comment: I know! We can start using them next week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have two loops instead of one to record the roll. Your code rolls and overwrites `total` `num_roll` times. Then you loop and try to update how many times each number was rolled. This should be done in one loop:

```
for (k = 0; k < num_roll; k++)
{
    roll_1 = rand() %6 +1;
    roll_2 = rand() %6 +1;
    total = roll_1 + roll_2;
    count++;

    if (total == 2) d2++;
    else if (total == 3) d3++;
    else if (total == 4) d4++;
    // ...
}
```

Also note, this is the type of construct that a `switch` statement solves:

```
switch( total )
{
     case 2: d2++; break;
     case 3: d3++; break;
     case 4: d4++; break;
     case 5: d5++; break;
     //...
     default: //Error
}
```

Comment: what I said, but better :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the first two loops into one, or else `total` will always be only the last roll you made.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You've been so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Total variable is inside a loop, so it value is going to be erased on each turn.
When you make the second loop, only last total value is going to be used.

You have two solutions,

First is build an array and store all total value. Then in second loop you can access all value.
Second, (the simple one) is to use the current value of total.

```
for (k = 0; k < num_roll; k++)
{
    roll_1 = rand() %6 +1;
    roll_2 = rand() %6 +1;
 ->    total = roll_1 + roll_2;
    count++;

    if (total == 2) d2++;
    else if (total == 3) d3++;
    else if (total == 4) d4++;
    // ...
}
```

If you need an extra explanations, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I can barely imagine why you would be given a task like this, yet not be allowed to use arrays. It's only going to teach you bad habits -- of which naming variables a1, a2, ... is one.

If you haven't yet been taught to use arrays, then this problem is not a suitable one to give you. If you *have* been taught to use arrays, then perhaps the challenge is to find an alternative syntax that's equivalent to an array.

```
 int *ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(int)); /* This isn't an array, but it's as good */
 memset(ptr,0,10);      /* Fill it with zeroes */

 /* Let's roll */
 for(i=0; i<num_roll; i++) {
     int roll = rand() % 6 + rand() %6; /* Our dice have sides from 0 to 5 */
     *(ptr + roll * sizeof(int)) ++; /* increment the appropriate part of our "array"
 }

 /* Print the results */
 for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {
     /* Add 2 to every roll for display, as if our dice had sides from 1 to 6 */
     printf("There were %d rolls with value %d\n", *(ptr+i), i+2);
 }
```